# Recipe from Ingredients HashMaps

Tags: java, hashmap, recipe

I have big problem with my project for University.

I have to write simple API of Coffe Machine.

I have Class Ingredients with HashMap  (Name and Value)
I want to create class Recipe with will have HashMap too with Name and Ingredients. How can I merge these HashMaps?

Here's my code:

```
public class Ingredient {

Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);


public HashMap<String, Integer> Ingredients = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

private String Name;
private int Value;

public void addIngredient(){
    Ingredients.put(scan.nextLine(), scan.nextInt());
}

Ingredient(String Name, int Value){
    this.Name = Name;
    this.Value = Value;
   }
}



public class Recipe{

private String name;
private Ingredient ingredient;

public HashMap<String, Ingredient> Drink = new HashMap<String, Ingredient>();

Recipe(String name, Ingredient ingredient){
    this.name = name;
    this.ingredient = ingredient;
  }
}
```

For example I want add to Ingredients, coffe, milk, water, sugar.
Then I want make drink with these igredients

Comment: So you want your Drink hashmap to point to a hashmap of Strings?

Comment: Yes, I think so.

Is there any other solution to solve this problem?

I have to make Recipe, then use WaterPump etc. to create Drink. Every drink has a diffrent recipe.